# how to move element from one point to another with animation?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with position absolute. I want to move it from one point to another say from (50,50) to (400,500). the points are change every time I click the button to move the element. I want to use animation for the transition.

How to do it in general solution or is there npm packages does that?

Comment: so where I can ask that?

Comment: Overly broad questions cannot be asked on SO. Perhaps Quora?

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple example for you (it's not production ready solution).

```js
function moveElement() {
  const div = document.getElementById('div');
  
  div.style.top = `${Math.random() * 200}px`;
  div.style.left = `${Math.random() * 200}px`;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="moveElement();">Move</button>

<div id="div"></div>
```

Maybe you just need to use libraries for animations.
For example: https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/ or http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/.

Answer (score 4):

you can use just pure JavaScript, here a little example, and animation is done by this line `transition: all .3s ease;`

```js
let left = document.getElementById('left');
let right = document.getElementById('right');
let redBox = document.querySelector('.element');
left.onclick = function(){
  let pos = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(redBox,null).getPropertyValue("left"), 10);
  let move = pos - 40;
  redBox.style.left = move + 'px'
}
right.onclick = function(){
  let pos = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(redBox,null).getPropertyValue("left"), 10);
  let move = pos + 40;
  redBox.style.left = move + 'px'
}
```

```css
.element{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
button{
  margin: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say that you should use different classes with different positions and just apply the different classes using javascript when the element is clicked. If you know the specific order of the positions you'll want to use, you can store each class name as a string in an array:

```
<button onclick="changePos()">Click me</button>

var positions = ['.pos1', '.pos2', '.pos3'];
var curPos = 0; 

function changePos(){
  $("#myElement").toggleClass(positions[curPos]);
  curPos++;
}
```